# Not able to see cloud option in Developer Services of Android Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, android-studio-2.2

I am trying to add Firebase to my project by checking Firebase option in Developer Services as shown below

[image: here]

but I can't see this option in Android Studio 2.2.

[image: here]

How can I get this option?

Answer (score 12):

The Cloud > Firebase checkbox has been removed in Android Studio 2.2, in favor of the new (and much more powerful) Firebase Assistant.

[image: Firebase Assistant in Android Studio]

You can find the Firebase Assistant through Tools > Firebase, after which it will open up.

Comment: so no more Cloud checkbox? It is automatic once I set up Firebase?

Comment: Any Firebase project is also a GCP project. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm new to Firebase, or Cloud something. I just followed a tutorial. :) 
I don't see anything - Cloud checkbox.

Answer (score 2):

To connect your app to Firebase directly in [Android Studio](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/firebase-plugin), proceed as follows:

1.Make sure you have downloaded the Google Repository version 26 or higher:

- Click Tools > Android > SDK Manager
- Click the SDK Tools tab.
- Select Google Repository, then click OK.
- Click Tools > Android > SDK Manager:

2.Open the Assistant window by clicking Tools > Firebase

3.Click to expand one of the listed features such as Analytics then click the Get Started tutorial to create a new Firebase project or connect to an existing one in a few clicks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to enable **cloud** option after *2.2 Android* version data will send to the database (Firebase) without enabling this option. 

So don't need to worry about this option go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

To manually enable and attach **Firebase** to your project by following two simple steps :

1. add internet permission in your project's manifest, like so :

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
   ```
2. add and compile the following  code in your project's `gradle.file`

   compile `com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1`

now you should be good to go ;